# How to redirect the user to My App when visiting my Website on Web Browser

Tags: android, mobile, linker

I have followed the following doc to implement deep link

```
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#java
```

However, when I try to type the URL in the browser it won't redirect the user to the App. Only if I click on the link it would take me to the App.

Answer (score 1):

If you type the URL in the browser redirecting to your app is not something that's done natively by default.

This can be achieved by writing some extra code on your website. You can check every time the page is a load if the user is coming from his android phone and call redirect with that same URL.

Make sure you properly verify your app links following the (https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations) tutorial so your users are not prompted with the view intent but redirected to the app properly.